# What does Sinatra return when no parameter is included in the route, but a symbol is set to match the parameter?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm expecting a GET request to come with parameters, and want to return an error response if the expected parameters aren't included. How can I check that the parameter has been included and return an error response if it isn't?

I'm trying to use an if statement, but don't know what to set the check against for when there's no parameter included in the GET request (i.e. the GET request is to /route or /route/);

```
get '/route/' do
    @symbol = params['parameter'];
    if @symbol == (what goes here?)
        return "Parameter missing error"
    else
        myfunction
    end
    erb :view
end
```

I'm using the @symbol value in another IF statement within myfunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, but I'll try to show you what I think you need:

```
get '/route/' do
    @symbol = params['parameter'];
    if params.key.include?('parameter')
        myfunction
    else
      return 'Parameter missing error'
    end
    erb :view
end
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry if my question wasn't clear, I guess simply I can't work out how you handle a call that doesn't have the correct parameters and then return an error response. I tried what you've suggested, but it throws an argument error, wrong number of arguments(0 for 1), when I make a GET call to /route (instead of /route/?parameter=value as intended).

Comment: Why not take the trailing slash off of the route?  So it says:

    get '/route' do

Comment: so I'd end up with a get '/route' do for call without parameters and a get '/route/' do for calls with parameters?

Comment: the url "/route?parameter=value" will match get "/route" as well

Comment: Great thanks, I'm just learning Ruby/Sinatra so thanks for all your help with the basics!

Comment: Also, in the above example, there is no need for the statement `@symbol = params['parameter']` since it isn't used elsewhere :) Edited the answer accordingly

Comment: You don't know that it isn't used in "myfunction"